# Usage of esc_url, esc_html, esc_attr ... functions

Tags: wordpress, escaping, sanitization

When are definitely needed or for a good practice to use escaping functions?

Such as using `esc_url();` with:

```
get_template_directory_uri();
get_permalink();
get_author_posts_url();
get_edit_post_link();
wp_get_attachment_url();
```

And `esc_html();` with:

```
get_the_title();
get_the_author();
get_the_date();
get_search_query();
```

Also I think `esc_html();` and `esc_attr();` are very similar, aren't they?  What are the differences?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### *Part 1*

According to the documentation - [Validating, Sanitizing, and Escaping](https://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/vip-go/validating-sanitizing-and-escaping/) by WP VIP team.

**Guiding Principles**

1. Never trust user input.
2. Escape as late as possible.
3. Escape everything from untrusted sources (like databases and users), third-parties (like Twitter), etc.
4. Never assume anything.
5. Never trust user input.
6. Sanitation is okay, but validation/rejection is better.
7. Never trust user input.

> “Escaping isn’t only about protecting from bad guys. It’s just making our software durable. Against random bad input, against malicious input, or against bad weather.” –nb

### *Part 2*

- Codex entry for [`esc_html`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html)
- Codex entry for [`esc_attr`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/)

According to the article - [Introduction to WordPress Front End Security: Escaping the Things](https://css-tricks.com/introduction-to-wordpress-front-end-security-escaping-the-things/) by Andy Adams from CSS-Tricks.

> Function: `esc_html`

Used for: Output that should have absolutely no HTML in the output.

What it does: Converts HTML special characters (such as `<`, `>`, `&`) into their "escaped" entity (`&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`).

> Function: `esc_attr`

Used for: Output being used in the context of an HTML attribute (think "title", "data-" fields, "alt" text).

What it does: The exact same thing as `esc_html`. The only difference is that different WordPress filters are applied to each function.

Comment: This kinds of begs the question: If `esc_html` and `esc_attr` do "the exact same thing," why are there two distinct functions?

Comment: @JimRatliff I dunno, but I normally use `esc_attr` for html attributes as suggested.

Comment: @JimRatliff By default, there is no difference between `esc_html` and `esc_attr`, the same code is used (they just have a different unused filter): https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/264698/what-is-the-difference-between-esc-html-filter-vs-attribute-escape-filter/264707#264707